# WIX: How to Select Features depending on properties

Tags: wix, parameters

I want to select features based on certain properties' values.

Similar to this question:
[WIX: How to Select Features From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246329/wix-how-to-select-features-from-command-line)

It seems that setting the ADDLOCAL property value is one way to do it, but is this the right way? Microsoft seems to warn against doing it in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367536(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use components instead of features? Components can be conditionally installed depending on various properties.

We do this having "pretend features" that a user can select via a checkbox, then a complicated set of conditionals to install various components depending on their Office version AND the state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Features can be conditionally installed as well.  See the Condition element under the Feature element.  Component Conditions may work as well.  Depends on your package structure.